# Writing files to publicly accessible documents folder in Android Q - Scoped Storage

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0, scoped-storage

## Background

After migrating to Android Q I can no longer find a suitable way to gain write access to the documents folder (`/storage/emulated/0/Documents`)

And before anyone mentions the many other questions on scoped storage I've read through many of them and from what I've seen so far all of the solutions use a app specific directory or accessing a media directory only (not documents folder access).

**From what I understand in Android Q I can either choose:**

- Use a app specific directory that is only accessible by my app (or apps I give permission to)
- Allow the user to select where they want the file stored (I think this can be a public location) `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

## Problem

The applications I develop are used to conduct tests on subjects, the data from the tests automatically gets stored in the publicly accessible Documents folder somewhat like: `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myAppName/subjectName/testData-todaysDate.pdf`

When the user wants to access the test data they plug their smartphone into a computer and navigate to the documents folder and the rest is pretty obvious. For this reason I have to use publicly accessible storage. Also imagine they want to open the test data on their phone via another app, Same deal!

## The solution I'm looking for

So the solution I'm looking for needs to be able to do the following:

- Doesn't ask for permission multiple times (once is ok)
- Automatically saves test data without user prompt (as hundreds of tests will be conducted)
- Saves to public documents folder e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/`
- Doesn't involve the user selecting the directory so NOT `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`
- Ideally the data is persistent so uninstalling the app doesn't cause data lose

I get that these changes in Android Q are to bring users more "into the loop" with how apps are accessing their data but once they understand how your app is using your data there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no solution meeting your requirements. If you switch from `Documents/` to `Downloads/`, you can [use `MediaStore.Downloads`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html). "but once they understand how your app is using your data there shouldn't be a problem" -- by that argument, you should not have a problem with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. The user needs to handle that exactly once, after which you can write as many documents into that tree as you like.

Comment: With `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` can they select a public location when they setup the app for example and then we reuse that forever? That might be the best solution then, still dangerous as the user can choose a bad location but better then nothing.

Comment: `When the user wants to access the test data they plug their smartphone into a computer and navigate to the documents folder`. Is this still possible with an Android Q device? Please report as i have no such device.

Comment: You can let the MediaStore write your files to /storage/emulated/0/Documents and /storage/emulated/0/Download and /storage/emulated/0/Pictures and /storage/emulated/0/DCIM without any permission needed.

Comment: "With `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` can they select a public location when they setup the app for example and then we reuse that forever?" -- yes.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61886002/4685284

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Android Q only.

```
String collection = "content://media/1c11-2404/file"; // One can even write to micro SD card
String relative_path = "Documents/MyFolder";

Uri collectionUri = Uri.parse(collection);

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, filesize);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, modified );
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relative_path);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)

Uri fileUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(collectionUri, contentValues);
```

Having an uri one can open an output stream to write the content for the file.

Comment: @blackapps: OK, I can confirm that this works. For external storage, you would use `content://media/external/file` (also available via `MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")`). For removable storage, you would need the storage ID (`1c11-2404` in your code snippet). I am skeptical that this is intended to work, so I would not be shocked if there are problems with this technique in future versions of Android. But, this is an excellent find -- thanks for sharing it!

Comment: Ok I'm slightly confused, before I was using `FileOutputStream` like so `outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath, false);` then I would simply `outputStream.write(dataToWrite.getBytes());` and then `.flush()` and `.close()` This only works with `File` of course, so I am not sure how you open an outputstream with a uri as you suggest?

Comment: `OutputStream is = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);`.

Comment: Ok between @blackapps and @CommonsWare I was able to piece together enough to get something working. This is absolutely brilliant but as others have said I'm not sure how intended this was.Also worth noting `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` will persist (even if removed) unless you clear the data/cache on your app.

Comment: regarding the UUID of an SD card, I found out it should be lowercase, contrary to what's returned from `StorageVolume` `getUuid()`

Answer (score 0):

try to put this line in your manifest file for android Q:

```
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in application tag.

Comment: That is a hack that will not work with versions after Q.