# Alternative to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory();

Tags: android, storage

#### My intention is to save a file available for the user in his internal storages `/Documents` path.

---

Since `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is deprecated now I am looking for an alternative.
Google tells me following alternatives:

- `getExternalFilesDir(String type)` from Context [[LINK]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))
- `MediaStore.Files` ← I don't get this anyway [[LINK]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.html)
- `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` where the user can specify the path himself [[LINK]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)

---

`getExternalFilesDir()` is not working - the way I use it - for my intention. This saves the files in the apps own directory where it is hardly accessible for the user, when I use `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` or `null` as the argument.

The intent one is a very good alternative I wanted to implement anyway but in my apps paid version. For the free version I want to store the file in a fixed location accessible for the user.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179299

Comment: @blackapps your approach works perfectly. thank you for your quick response. I will answer my question on how solved this task it in detail tomorrow.