# Create Folder in usb android non root device?

Tags: java, android, usb, storage

Unable to create a folder or file in USB storage android version above 5.0+ non-root device using this method

File dest = new File("storage/usbotg/usbname/foldername");
dest.mkdir();

I will successfully created a file or folder in internal storage using ndk c by below code .
FILE* fp = fopen("/sdcard/sample.txt","w+");

but unable to create usb storage via appliaction .

FILE* fp = fopen("/storage/2F5A-E677/sample.txt","w+");

Comment: Yes we already know that long time. Any questions?.

Comment: can u give any idea to how can i solve it ? u given for  Android Q . But i want to support from Android 5.0.

Comment: Android Q, what about it ?

Comment: i got this kind of exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/12B1-1800/file

Comment: There is no code that could cause such an exception.

Comment: i just tried your sample snippet code in Android 5.0 . Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179299/writing-files-to-publicly-accessible-documents-folder-in-android-q-scoped-stor/60

Comment: Also i mentioned write external storage permission in manifest.xml file.

Comment: You should post the used code in your post. We dont know what you are doing at all.

Comment: String relative_path = "Documents/Myfoldername";
String collection = "content://media/12B1-1800//file";
Uri collectionUri = Uri.parse(collection);
byte[] data = new String("Hello").getBytes();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "hello.txt");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, data.length);
Uri fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(collectionUri, contentValues);